# Enable input selection but disable text entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if there is a way to allow a form to be selected (clicked) but at the same time make the form unable to have text entered.

I've tried using `readonly` which gave me the functionality but the cursor it provides is the same as if I set `disabled=true` and it greys out the input field which is confusing for the user. Is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input class="notype" />

$('.notype').on('keydown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

What you haven't told us is why. If it's because you want it to be copied to clipboard but not changed, the above won't let you do that, if so please elaborate.

Comment: Great! Thanks, works really well. The reason I want to do it is because I have a date range field and I am using a date picker to select the date. I don't really want users to input dates themselves, because then it gets messy and I have to do a whole bunch of other validation so I want to force them to use the date picker.